# HashiCorp Vault Database Secrets display Connection URL

Tags: mysql, hashicorp-vault

Following:

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/mysql-maria/

I want to display `connection_url` or database host along with userpass when I query Vault via:

`vault read database/creds/my-role`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't mind me asking, could I ask why you need the connection_url. If it is to provide to an application for config you can potentially use Vault template?

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/agent/template/

As the user2599522 said it is not possible directly with Vault but a simple bash script or template will do the trick. All depends on the use case for the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The use case is new\existing devs needs DB RO access from SREs. With Vault, process becomes much easier. New\existing devs also need to know `connection_url` in order to connect via client or apps. I thought with `vault read` will ideally prevent us from writing a bash script. I think writing bash script will do the trick. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think there is a really elegant solution here and definitely worth spending the effort of building a workflow. Two things I am thinking, write a little dev utility `creds` you pass it some simple parameters such as the db you want credentials for and it authenticates you with Vault (maybe using Github) and returns a connection string. Or even better `db_proxy` you run DB proxy and it fetches the credentials from vault and exposes a localhost connection for the dev which is pre-authenticated. Again use GitHub creds or LDAP to auth Vault automatically.

Comment: It does require a little building but the Vault API is super sane and really easy to integrate with. There are also client libraries for a number of languages. If you do that then you get two things abstraction which is always good, and the workflow is perfect for your needs. Oh and the possibility to open source a pretty dope tool.

Answer (score 1):

Im afraid that is not possible with the current db plugins.

Other possible solutions are to create a KV with the connection url and retrieve that. To maintain consistency, you can keep the same path as the creds, for example

db creds with `vault read database/creds/my-role`
and connection string with `vault read kv/database/creds/my-role`

This means that you have some overhead when you are setting up vault and when you are retrieving the credentials

Another option is to [read the database config](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/databases/index.html#read-connection) from the API.

This will yield back something like

```
{
  "data": {
    "allowed_roles": ["readonly"],
    "connection_details": {
      "connection_url": "{{username}}:{{password}}@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/",
      "username": "root"
    },
    "plugin_name": "mysql-database-plugin"
  }
}
```

where you can get the `connection_url` and regex it to get the connection string. I think this requires more effort as your client needs to know how to convert the connection string (comparing it with the first solution i mentioned where the KV is generated when you are generating the database engine config)